# Efficient selection from multiple tables, for values selected from another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I'd like to select from multiple identically constructed tables returning values of three columns for each row where a value of one of the columns is found by another query. For example, an inefficient way to do this might be:

```
Select Film_Title, Main_Actor, Run_Time From Film_Table_1
  Where Film_Title in
       (Select Film_Title
          From Awesome_Films_Table
          Where Film_Year equals "1984")
UNION ALL
Select Film_Title, Main_Actor, Run_Time From Film_Table_2
  Where Film_Title in
       (Select Film_Title
          From Awesome_Films_Table
          Where Film_Year equals "1984")
Select Film_Title, Main_Actor, Run_Time From Film_Table_3
  Where Film_Title in
       (Select Film_Title
          From Awesome_Films_Table
          Where Film_Year equals "1984")
Select Film_Title, Main_Actor, Run_Time From Film_Table_4
  Where Film_Title in
       (Select Film_Title
          From Awesome_Films_Table
          Where Film_Year equals "1984");
```

In reality, I have many 'Film_Table_#' to select from. Can anyone advise how to achieve this more efficiently? I presume replacing:

```
Select Film_Title
            From Awesome_Films_Table
            Where Film_Year equals "1984"
```

That I currently have on each Where specifier with a single variable defined at the start might help, but I'm not sure how that might be achieved.

Comment: These tables should be combined into one, where the table number is the first field in the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this in Oracle:

1. equals should have been made as =
2. " should have been made as '
3. Worst design to have one table per film. Ideally it should have been one row per film in a centralised table (Go for NF if needed
   )

> ```
> WITH AFT
>   AS (SELECT
>            FILM_TITLE TITLE
>       FROM
>            AWESOME_FILMS_TABLE
>       WHERE
>            FILM_YEAR = '1984')
> SELECT
>     FILM_TITLE,
>     MAIN_ACTOR,
>     RUN_TIME
> FROM
>     FILM_TABLE_1,
>     AFT
> WHERE
>     FILM_TITLE = TITLE
> UNION ALL
> SELECT
>     FILM_TITLE,
>     MAIN_ACTOR,
>     RUN_TIME
> FROM
>     FILM_TABLE_2,
>     AFT
> WHERE
>     FILM_TITLE = TITLE
> UNION ALL
> SELECT
>     FILM_TITLE,
>     MAIN_ACTOR,
>     RUN_TIME
> FROM
>     FILM_TABLE_3,
>     AFT
> WHERE
>     FILM_TITLE = TITLE
> UNION ALL
> SELECT
>     FILM_TITLE,
>     MAIN_ACTOR,
>     RUN_TIME
> FROM
>     FILM_TABLE_4,
>     AFT
> WHERE
>     FILM_TITLE = TITLE;</li>
> ```